Why inplace masking doesn't work when dataframe columns are referenced using loc like this?
Applying the mask method to this dataframe should substitute 0 with NaN's according to docs, but doesn't. Why?
import pandas as pd

# create a test dataframe.
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                     'b': ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two'],
                     'c': [2, None, 23, 0],
                     'd': [0, 3, 3, None]})
print(test_df)

returns:

Below code should apply the mask in place on the test_df, but doesn't:
# delete zeroes in columns c and d.
test_df.loc[:, ['c','d']].mask(0 == test_df.loc[:, ['c','d']], inplace = True)
print(test_df)

returns the same result.

The dataframe remains unchanged as if the values were changed on a copy, not on the original dataframe despite being correctly referenced using 'loc' for overwriting.
Meanwhile this less specific addressing without loc ..
test_df.mask(0 == test_df[['c','d']], inplace = True)

.. successfully substitutes the zeroes with NaN's:


Yes indeed, it answers my question. Thank you.
